# Why don’t mathematicians work on ‘difference-asymptotic’ of prime counting function?

Tags: prime-numbers

Mathematicians back in 19th century tried to find a function that satisfies $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\pi(x)}{f(x)}=1$$ and $f(x)$ turns out to be $\frac{x}{\ln x}$, or any function asymptotic to it(like $\text{Li}(x)$). They proved it rigorously and now it is known as the Prime Number Theorem.

However, I don’t see much work on finding a function that satisfies $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(\pi(x)-g(x))=0$$ As far as I know, $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(\pi(x)-\frac{x}{\ln x})=\infty$$ so $\frac{x}{\ln x}$ cannot be a candidate of $g(x)$.

Moreover, if such function is discovered, it will be very useful in the sense that estimation of number of primes below some large $N$ can become more and more precise as $N$ grows. This would surely be more powerful than PNT.

Why only little work has done by mathematicians to figure out $g(x)$?

Comment: Well, even the Riemann hypothesis implies only $\pi(x) - \text{li}(x) = O(\sqrt{x}\log x).$  Since $\text{li}(x)$ is continuous and $\pi(x)$ is highly discontinuous, studying the difference isn't very profitable.  It seems to be to be almost equivalent to asking, "what numbers are prime?"

Comment: But, we can contrast the study of $\pi(x)$ with the partition function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function , which has (an exact!) $g(x)$ in the form of an infinite series.

Comment: Such a function would essentially encode all information about sufficiently large prime numbers.  For example, you could tell whether $x$ was prime by looking at $g(x)$ and $g(x-1)$.

Comment: @Jair: So basically, it'd have to be $\pi(x)$ up to some lower order error term that vanishes in the limit.  That's actually pretty boring, unless you've got a closed form of some kind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In brief, because what you're suggesting is overwhelmingly more powerful than the multiplicative difference, to the point where none of the known techniques can even come close. It's not that this *isn't* studied; indeed, 'additive differences' on the PNT and related functions - but as noted in a comment, they're usually only as good as being able to say $\pi(x)=f(x)+O(x^\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$ (typically with $\alpha\gt 1/2$). Note that these sorts of asymptotics imply the 'multiplicative' equalities you mention (since then $\pi(x)/f(x)=1+O^*(x^{\alpha-1})$), but the additive results you're requesting are even stronger than reducing $\alpha$ to zero.

Answer (score 4):

The question you are suggesting, in its exact form, would basically be a lost fight. Should you be able to find such function $g(x)$, this would mean
$$\forall \epsilon > 0\ \exists x_0 \in \mathbb{N}\ \forall x \in \mathbb{N}, x > x_0: |\pi(x) - g(x)| < \epsilon.$$
If you plug in $\epsilon = 1/2$, this tells you that from some $x_0$ on the function value $g(x)$ differs from the $x$-th prime by less than a half, in other words, that you could just *round it to the nearest integer* to get the $x$-th prime. I doubt anyone nowadays hopes that a closed form like that could be found.